# How to post event to a dialog when a video capture device is connected in java

Tags: java

I am trying to post an Event or notification to a `dialog` or `frame` , when a video capture device is connected to a system.(Mac OS X). I am trying to do it with java .
Any help would be far kind.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html). Its [CaptureDeviceManager](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/CaptureDeviceManager.html) class seems to offer the required facilities. I've shortly experimented with JMF and found it to be quite easy to get a stream from a webcam and output it to a Swing container. Took minimal effort.

Comment: Hi Thanks for ur kind reply. But I m trying to get device info and want to show message when any video capture device is connected to system.

Comment: The `CaptureDeviceManager` class has a method `getDeviceList`. It will return a vector of `CaptureDeviceInfo` objects which will tell you something about the available devices. I don't know if the method will return an updated list when a new device was connected after it was called for the first time, or whether the device must first be added to the JMF configuration, but that's what I'm saying you should check out. If this does provide live data automatically, periodically checking the returned vector for new entries could be used to detect added devices.

Comment: Thanks alot ... I am doing that but I don't want to check periodically . I want a notification as in window WM_DEVICECHANGE .

Comment: @VrijendraKumarSingh Not sure there's gonna be a convenient way to do that in Java apart from using JNI. Maybe there's some device manager access somewhere. I'll let you know if I come across it.